# Identity Server 4 - Audience validation failed error

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I encounter this error in my API `IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44337/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'joborderingapi' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'`

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days already and can't figure out yet about how to solve it.

I have the following applications:

1. Client App (Angular 7)
2. Identity Server
3. API

I was able to login successfully to Identity Server in my Client app and was able to get the token but when I used the token to connect to the API method it throws this error `IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://localhost:44337/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'joborderingapi' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.`

I followed the answer from [Identity Server 4 with EF Identity DB Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492579/identity-server-4-with-ef-identity-db-issue) and checked the three tables (ApiResources, ApiScopes, ClientScopes), the values are correct, `joborderingapi`is enabled in ApiResources, in ApiScopes it is linked to ApiResource and in ClientScopes it is linked to the Client

Here is my API Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var apiIdpAuthority = Configuration["AppSettings:IdpAuthority"];
        var apiName = Configuration["AppSettings:ApiName"];
        var apiSecret = Configuration["AppSettings:ApiSecret"];
        var requireHttps = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["AppSettings:RequireHttps"]);
        var httpsPort = Configuration["AppSettings:HttpsPort"];
        var applicationUrl = Configuration["AppSettings:ApplicationUrl"];

        services.Configure<ClientAppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ClientAppSettings"));
        services.AddDbContext<JobOrderingDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("JobOrderingDB")));

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = apiIdpAuthority;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = requireHttps;
                options.ApiName = apiName;
                options.ApiSecret = apiSecret;
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins(apiIdpAuthority, applicationUrl)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
          {
              options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
          });

        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.Preload = true;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
        });

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = Convert.ToInt32(httpsPort);
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors("default");

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        var locale = Configuration["SiteLocale"];
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-US") };

        if (supportedCultures.Where(x => x.Name == locale).Count() == 0)
        {
            supportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo(locale));
        }

        RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        {
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale)
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Identity Server Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //var microsoftClientId = Configuration["MicrosoftClientId"];
        //         var microsoftClientSecret = Configuration["MircosoftClientSecret"];
        var azureADClientId = Configuration["AzureADClientId"];
        var azureADClientSecret = Configuration["AzureADClientSecret"];
        var azureADEndPoint = Configuration["AzureADEndPoint"];
        var issuerUri = Configuration["IssuerUri"];

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddAuthentication()
       //     .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("AAD", "Azure AD", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", azureADEndPoint);
                options.ClientId = azureADClientId;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
            });

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;            

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()                .AddSigninCredentialFromConfig(Configuration.GetSection("SigninKeyCredentials"), _logger)
            // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // this will do the initial DB population
       // InitializeDatabase(app);

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Note:** I only encounter this issue when I use the local login.  It is working fine if I use the Azure AD login, I was able to connect to the API using the authorization token from the client app

Comment: What do you mean by local login? The token is valid when you login using the angular client?

Comment: Yes, the token is valid in the Angular client. The local login is the internal username and password, it was called as Local Login in the identity server demo page. https://demo.identityserver.io/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fgrants

Comment: I just found the issue.  It is in the Consent Screen Views/Consent/Index.cshtml of the Identity Server app.  The issue was encountered because the Identity sever never receives consent for access to my API since the checkbox that asks the user for consent to the API Resource Scopes was commented out in the code. It worked after I removed the comment in the code